# Getting an undefined index error

Tags: php, mysql, undefined-index

my php is very "weak" so I am having trouble with this -

```
<?php

include_once "../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";

$title = $_POST['title'];
$desc = $_POST['description'];

$query = mysql_query("UPDATE images SET title='$title', description='$desc'") or die (mysql_error());

echo 'Operation Completed Successfully! <br /><br /><a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
exit();
?>
```

The undefined index error is `description` on line 9 which is `$desc = $_POST['description'];` and "description" is in the database spelling is also right.

Comment: it has nothing to do with the database field name.. do you have a form that sends data to this script, using post as a request method and "description" as one of the fields?

Comment: Database?! `$_POST` is about POST values, not the database. And you have an SQL injection vulnerability, which comments/answers on **every single one** of the other posts that you allegedly checked out would have told you.

Comment: this isn't online ,nor will it ever go online so I do not have to worry about injections. I'm still learning but this has helped me understand what I am doing. 

I have found that some people on this site are very condescending!"

Comment: @Aasim: Direct, perhaps, and occasionally impatient to certain things. Just because we don't plaster our responses with smilies doesn't mean we're not nice people! After all, we _are_ spending our time on you for free.

Comment: -1 For "this isn't online ,nor will it ever go online", 50% of fraud happens by insiders in an organization. SQL-injection is just as much a problem for intranets as it is for the internet. And besides, if you know about the issue, how much work is it just to type `$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);` Nothing to do with looking down on people.

Comment: I understand your concerns about injections, but only I am using this. Its personal project that I am working on just trying to learn about php, its not an issue to just type that what you said, just that I don't know much about injections.

Comment: Also about people sounding condescending, I say this as some people will gladly help taking into consideration the level of the person asking the question - they won't question the person - if you cannot do that then don't read the question, don't answer the question. The answers here helped me understand my mistake and I thank them all. In this case it was my fault as the mistake was in a typing error, so if I have offended anyone I am sorry.

Comment: Wish I could downvote every comment from a SO newcomer that requests certain people not to answer or comment on certain questions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try doing:

```
if(isset($_POST['description'])){echo "yes";}else{echo "no";}
```

This wont fix it but it will help determing whether $_POST['description'] exists.. Also, what is the source of `$_POST['description']`?, is it set in `../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php`? How?

Unless performing more complex tasks (i.e. AJAX), POST variables are typically set by submitting a form- does your code come after the page is loaded following a form submission? If not, you may be incorrectly using _POST variables...

If `$_POST['description']` is set somewhere in the code of `../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php`, and by including the file you wish to then retrieve its value- you may be going about things wrongly- can you provide information about the origin of `$_POST['description']`?

Comment: the answer was no, but I think I have fixed it - see comment below!

Comment: Why would an included script set anything in `$_POST`? It certainly shouldn't. `$_POST` is an automatic superglobal containing HTTP POST data.

Comment: @Tomalak, thats the point- I wrote that above. As you say, you shouldnt.

Comment: As clearly stated in the last paragraph of the answer... 'you may be going about things wrongly'

Comment: But your answer did help me understand my mistake

Comment: No, this is true, apologies the above response was in relation to  Tomalak's comment

Answer (score 1):

Your form needs to send this information to the php file. It seems as you only have `title` in your form and not `description`. You should post your form for better help.

```
<form ...>
  <input type="text" name="description" value="">
  <input type="text" name="title" value="">
</form>
```

You should always escape your data which you are using in SQL queries.

Comment: I think you might have it, just testing it now, the part that was supposed to be description was title, copy and paste .... I think I need more coffee!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, a `description` field is not present in the `$_POST` array, thus index `description` does not point to anything.

What does `var_dump($_POST);` print?

Also, is this an internal system? If not, you should read up on SQL injections.

Comment: thanks for the reply - but I think I have just made a stupid error - the description isn't coming through as the form was not set as description, rather as title - just a copy and paste error!

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with index `description` in the `$_POST` array.

Try `var_dump($_POST);` before that line to examine the array. (Alternatively, if some information is cut, use `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: thanks but I found the mistake!